# How to read Json file from resources into JQuery in Maven JSF application?

Tags: jquery, json, maven, jsf

I trying to read sample.Json file data which is placed in src/main/resources/sample.json in maven JSF application.
My Jquery code is

```
 $.getJSON("/sample.json", function(data) {
    $('#tree1').tree({
        data: data
    });
}
```

);
But, above code was not taking path and data.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: and exactly what does `not taking path and data` mean? Use browser console to provide more meaningful troubleshooting information

Answer (score 0):

Files placed in src/main/resources will only be accessible via the java classpath, and not through javascript. You probably want to put it in src/main/webapp instead.

Comment: You mean, should I keep sample.json in webapp folder? If so, what is the path I need to mention in JQuery code??

Comment: Correct. Files under the webapp folder will get deployed to the root of your web application so you should be able to reference it just as you have it in your code - "/sample.json"

Comment: Can you please look into above posted answer by me??